# Vim. Can't yank non-eng chars to system clipboard

Tags: vim, neovim

When I yank russian characters, say `тест`, to system clipboard ("+y) and then paste it in a shell or a browser I get this `—Ç–µ—Å—Ç`. How to fix this?

Vim

```
:set encoding?
encoding=utf-8
:set fileencoding
fileencoding=utf-8
```

Shell

```
echo $LC_CTYPE
UTF-8
```

Comment: `:checkhealth provider`

Comment: @Matt
```
health#provider#check
========================================================================
## Clipboard (optional)
  - OK: Clipboard tool found: pbcopy
```
Plus errors for python and warnings for ruby and node.js

Comment: Not sure what could be wrong then. Check if your pbcopy/pbpaste work okay. BTW. Neovim only supports `encoding=utf-8` anyway, and `fileencoding` is not relevant either.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and fixed it by adding `lang en_US.UTF-8` to my `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` (using Neovim). You could try adding that to your `~/.vimrc`.

Source: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/5683#issuecomment-420833679

Answer (score 0):

Setting correct locale for a shell with these lines added to `.zshenv` solves the issue.

```
set -a
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
set +a
```